# How to enable device administrator for exchange after user has declined

Tags: 2.2-froyo, exchange, device-administrator, activation

it appears that a user has declined the device administrator prompt for an exchange email account on samsung galaxy. It doesnt prompt anymore just displays a message about requiring a device administrator, but in the setting>location & security>device admin there are no options at all and nothing displyed.
 Is there another menu option somewhere to enable the device administrator for exchange after it has been declined?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have asked for the right permissions in manifest.
Also check your manifest declarations
Check your xml file.
For reference check this
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: OP didn't ask for his own app (development questions are off-topic here). Moreover, the corresponding permission must have been registered in the Manifest – or the user could not have "declined the device administrator prompt". Thus I'm afraid this does not answer the question.